# EDM column issues outlook

Tags: html, outlook, html-table, multiple-columns, html-email

I am building an EDM email and I am trying to have it look consistent across multiple mail servers and responsive for different devices sizes.

I have coded it using `<table>` tags. I have 1 part which should appear as 2 columns on a desktop and as a 1 column on mobile.

This is working on mobile,gmail, multiple browsers etc.. However it does not look correct on outlook. The columns will not sit next to each other. They seem to be too wide to sit next to each other on outlook. I have continued to reduce the width to resolve this issue. However it does not work.

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center" width="90%">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="36%" align="left" class="fullWidthBlockMobile">
                <tr><td height="15"></td></tr>
                <tr>
                    <td valign="top" style="color:#ffffff; font-weight: normal; -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;">
                        <font face="'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial">[firstname,fallback=Hi there],</font><br/><br/>
                        <font face="'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</font><br/><br/>
                        <font style="color:#00AFEF; font-weight: bold; -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;" face="'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial">Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,</font><br/><br/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>

            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="54%" align="right" class="fullWidthBlockMobile">
                <tr><td height="15"></td></tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="center" valign="top">
                        <img src="images/card.png" alt="" style="max-width:100%"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

`<!--[if mso | IE]>` works on Outlook, so you can try it like this

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="font-size:0px;" border="0" width="100%">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="text-align:left;vertical-align:top;border:none;font-size:0px;padding:0px;">
        <!--[if mso | IE]>
          <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
        <![endif]-->
        <!--[if mso | IE]>
            <td width="50%" style="width:50%;">
          <![endif]-->
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width:50%;" align="left" border="0">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td style="text-align:left;" align="left" valign="top"></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
        <!--[if mso | IE]>
            </td>
          <![endif]-->
        <!--[if mso | IE]>
            <td width="50%" style="width:50%;">
          <![endif]-->
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width:50%;" align="left" border="0">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td style="text-align:left;" align="left" valign="top"></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
        <!--[if mso | IE]>
            </td>
          <![endif]-->
        <!--[if mso | IE]>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        <![endif]-->
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```